# COUNTIF by month for range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns in excel that track when someone answered a call by date. Each person is called up to 3 times, hence the 3 columns. I am trying to count the number of people that answered in July, so the first two columns could be pre-July, or the first column could be in July. My data looks a little like this.

```
      A          B          C          D
1  1st Call   2nd Call   3rd Call     July
2  01/06/15   12/06/15   22/06/15     No
3  01/06/15   15/06/15   02/07/15     Yes
4  14/06/15   02/07/15                Yes
5  14/06/15   03/07/15                Yes
6  05/07/15                           Yes
```

So regardless of whether they answered after 1, 2, or 3 attempts, if any of the 3 columns is in July it returns "Yes".

I have tried this formula,

```
=IF(A2="", "", IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2, month=7)>0, "Yes", "No"))
```

and

```
=IF(A2="", "", IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2, MONTH(A2:C2)=7)>0, "Yes", "No"))
```

But to no avail. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

EDIT

I have realised since I can use the following,

```
=IF(A2="","", IF(MONTH(A2)=7, "Yes", IF(MONTH(B2)=7, "Yes", IF(MONTH(C2)=7, "Yes", "No"))))
```

However i'm still curious if my first attempt is achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you're attempting with a simple tweak to how you are declaring your 'array' of possible responses:

```
=OR(IF(A2="", "", IF(Month(A2:C2))=7, TRUE, FALSE)))
```

You will need to confirm this with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, rather than just ENTER. It will work as you are intuiting, by running over each cell with the formula If(Month(CELL)>0, TRUE, FALSE). It then gives us an array of responses, depending on the results. [something like {TRUE, FALSE, TRUE}].

Note that I needed to change "yes" and "no" to TRUE / FALSE, because then we can wrap the whole thing in an OR statement. Otherwise, it's hard to pick out from your array of "yes"'s and "no"'s whether any of them are "yes". You can, if you need to, wrap this whole thing in an IF formula to convert TRUE to "yes", like so:

```
=IF(FORMULA ABOVE,"yes","no")
```

Comment: Note that if you were doing something "the other way", by checking the month of a single cell, and seeing if it equalled, say, 5, 6, or 9, you could do: =OR(IF(MONTH(A2)={5,6,9},TRUE,FALSE)). This could be entered as a regular formula, without needing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. This is only possible if the "array of values to check" is hardcoded, not based on a range of multiple cells.

Comment: Thank you for this, I can't quite see where its checking for a specific month though? Which bit checks to see if any value in the array is July for example?

Comment: @TimWilkinson Ah, my formula before was checking to see if there was a month entered at all - now entered to see if the month = 7.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use an Or statement? `=if(or(month(a2)=7,month(b2)=7,month(c2)=7),"Yes","No")`.  Then, you can use a countif to count how many "Yes" answers you have.

As for whether your first method would work, AFAIK it won't as the array in the formula won't work.  Also, it's a little "overkill" to use an `if countif > 0, then ...` since all you want to know is if ANY of them are July, you could just use the above `Or()` statement.